# Ansible copy module requires writable parent directory?

Tags: ansible

Need to set /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding to 1

That's can be easily done via command

```
- name: Enable IPv4 traffic forwarding
  command: echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding
```

But that's bad practice - it will be always "changed" task.

So I tried the following:

```
- name: Enable IPv4 traffic forwarding
  copy: content=1 dest="/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding" force=yes
```

Which failed with msg: "Destination /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all not writable"

According to [sources](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/d71b9bae893e5cb860eb7717af93d00363b3890c/files/copy.py#L298) seems like copy always requires parent directory will be writable. But 1) I don't understand why 2) Any other "idiomatic" way to set destination file to required value?

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/sysctl_module.html ?

Comment: Would switching to 'synchronize' module fix the problem?

Comment: `command: echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding`

will literally echo '1 > /proc/sys...', not write to the file- `command` doesn't run things through the shell, so shell metacharacters won't work. You need/want `shell: echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding`.

Comment: synchronise is based on rsync which creates new files in the same directory, so a writeable directory is needed, UNLESS you use an option specify a specific directory!

Answer (score 3):

While I still do not understand why copy needs to check parent directory permissions, thanks to @larsks:

[sysctl module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/sysctl_module.html) changes both sysctl.conf and /proc values

and this solves my task

Comment: As a hint to e.g change `/proc/sys/kernel/keys/maxkeys` set `name: kernel.keys.maxkeys`

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Enable IPv4 traffic forwarding
  copy: content=1 dest="/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding" unsafe_writes=true
```

will disable Ansible's atomic write functionality, and instead write `1` to the file directly.

Atomic writes are good and useful because they mean you will never get a corrupted file that has the output of multiple processes interleaved, but `/proc` is a special magic thing. The classic Unix dance of writing to a temporary file until you're done, and then renaming it to the final filename you want breaks because `/proc` doesn't let you create random temporary files.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this problem:

```
  - name: Create temp copy of mongod.conf
    copy:
      src : /etc/mongod.conf
      dest: /tmp/mongod.conf
      remote_src: yes
    diff: no
    check_mode: no
    changed_when: false

  - name: Copy config file mongod.conf
    copy:
      src : "/source/of/your/mongod.conf" 
      dest: "/tmp/mongod.conf"
    register: result

  - name: Copy temp mongod.conf to /etc/mongod.conf
    shell: "cp --force /tmp/mongod.conf /etc/mongod.conf"
    when: result.changed == true
```

Comment: I suppose that will work but it is a very round about solution!  Must be a better way!