# Ansible: /etc not writable

Tags: ansible

I am trying to copy a file in to /etc. But I am getting "msg: Destination /etc not writable" when i run the playbook. Here is my Playbook task part. Really Appreciate your help.

tasks:

```
- name: copy rsyslog
  sudo: yes
  copy:
      src: /home/nandakumar.nachimuth/playbooks/rhn_check/rtest.conf
      dest: /etc/rtest.conf
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: 0755
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Error

`msg: Destination /etc not writable`

Note:I have provided the ssh and sudo pass while running the Playbook.

Comment: You should really get the formatting of the question right. Anyway, sudo ( become in v2 ) has to be specified outside tasks. You can either run the playbook with `-vvvv` to see the commands ansible runs or you can actually connect to the host and try to write a file in /etc/

Comment: Yes, I am able to write into /etc with sudo. Only Through Playbook I am getting "msg: Destination /etc not writable"

Comment: Try specifying sudo after `- hosts: `

Comment: "ssh connection closed waiting for sudo password prompt"  - This is the error message now, when giving sudo: yes after hosts.

Comment: What about this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61663261/3027266 in case you don't have `sudo` privileges

Comment: Is this issue resolved? I am facing same issue. getting error 'Destination not writable'. When I run sudo copy src_file dest_file in command line, it works fine.

Answer (score 29):

Instead of using `sudo` with your tasks, try adding `become: yes` with your playbook

example

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
```

Also, make sure that you are really entering the `sudo` password instead of the user password.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reconfigure sshd to allow your user to switch to use sudo without password. To do that you will have to fire up `sudo visudo` and then change the line with your user to look like this:

```
your_username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And that will do the trick.

Comment: No, you don't need to do this; that's why `--ask-sudo-pass` exists.

Comment: I agree with that, but that's not what you said.  OP doesn't *need* to reconfigure sudo to be passwordless, but they *should*.

Comment: is there anyother way to test without modifying sudoers files?

Comment: @Nandu what is there more to test? The error you got is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

The user should have root permissions.

I think this should help. My issue was though user1 has root permissions i was getting unable to write error, Just by placing "become: yes", I get rid of this error.

```
- hosts: analytics
  user: user1
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: yes
  roles:
    - name: xxxxx
```

Comment: Don't use `become: yes` at the playbook level! It always should be explicitly set to `become: no`. Use privilege escalation only for the specific tasks.

Comment: @Dzintars Why? E.g. if all tasks need the elevation, it would be verbose to repeat the `become: yes` in all of them.

Comment: @aderchox If only you know what you are doing. In my experience i almost never seen a single playbook which requires root privileges for all tasks. Even then, for sake of convention it is better to be a little bit verbose. This verbosity has huge potential to save you from bunch of problems especially if executing on running systems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify sudo after user with hosts
example:

```
-hosts: abc
 user: xyz
 sudo: yes
```

This will work for you.